# How to refresh gridview after insertion in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, fill

I am using gridview in a page of website that I am builing with asp.net so I am using sqldatasource component to fill gridview.now I insert new data into the table and page is refreshed but new data is not displayed in the gridview how to solve this problem

[image: See Image]

Comment: there is no code.I saeid I am using sqldatasource component

Comment: @user6440832 Bind your `GridView` after insertion of data. Then you can see your added `data`

Answer (score 0):

Bind your gridview again after inserting new data. It will take time but you have to fetch the data from database and bind it again to gridview.

```
Gridview.DataSource = yourDataSource;
Gridview.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Grid in page_Init()

It bind the data from your database Every page init

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on inserting using SqlDataSource - [SqlDataSource.Insert Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)

And here's a complete, wroking example:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class SqlDataSourceExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name], [Surname] FROM [Person]"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Person](Name,Surname)VALUES(@name,@surname)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtName" Name="name" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSurname" Name="surname" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text="Surname"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="btnInsert_Click" />
</form>
```